# Axis Labels in R: p(Y=y | theta = something)

Tags: r, axis-labels

I've searched all over and can't find the code for having a conditional sign as in

p(a|b)

The code (generic R code, not ggplot) I'm using is

```
ylab = bquote(Pr( Y == y |  theta == .(mytheta) , n == .(n)))
```

What this gives me for a label is

Pr(|(Y=y,theta=0.2), n=10)

Where the theta is a proper Greek symbol, mytheta is 0.2, and n is 10.
So all that's not working is the conditional sign.  It looks to me like R is taking the | for an or...

I haven't tried ggplot yet, but would like to get this working in plain R first.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `bquote(Pr( Y == y ~'|'~  theta == .(mytheta) , n == .(n)))` seems to work

Comment: This worked for me and seems the most elegant!  Thanks! I'd mark it as the answer but I don't see that option here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was pretty interesting to see that 'pipe' (vs. 'OR') get parsed into Polish notation. The conditional-bar can be accessed with the Symbol font using the methods described in `?plotmath` and `?points`

```
plot(1,1, main=bquote(Pr( Y == y ~ symbol("\275") ~ theta == .(mytheta) , n == .(n))))
```

(I did try making a SPECIAL user-defined function using `%|%` as the missing conditional symbol, but failed.)

To your comment-question asking for an illustration (actually two versions of how to use `substitute` in an equivalent manner:

```
mytheta = 0.2
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), ylab= substitute(P(Y~"|"~ mytheta ), list(mytheta=mytheta)) )
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), ylab= substitute(P(Y~"|"~ theta == mytheta ), 
                                                    list(mytheta=mytheta))  )
 # Second version prints greek-theta == value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works nicely.  I like user20650's better, but it is essentially the same as yours.  I just don't have to remember the symbol number with it.  Thanks to  you both for the help!

Comment: It's really a matter of convenience/memory versus typesetting purity. I'm not going to be offended if you change to a checkmark for the user-memory aspect. I'll add a response to your comment-question to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I always just use `expression`. I haven't used `bquote` before.

#### edited

Sorry, I did a bunch of these and obviously exported the wrong one. Use `paste` not `paste0`.

```
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), ylab= expression(paste("P(Y| ", theta," )")))
```

[image]

Comment: Alex: Are you being confused by the fact that there is a `paste()`-plotmath function? It's not the same as the paste function that operates on character vectors.

Comment: @42- I may have just exported the wrong plot, but I think you might be right

Comment: @Alex.. i dont think expression is the right tool here as the op wants to substitute in the values.that theta takes (hence bquote / or you could use substitute) .

Comment: `substitute(expression( ... , list(token=val)))` can be used in place of `bquote`. But `bquote` has economy of expression going for it.

Comment: @42-: I don't understand the list(token=val) part... couldn't make it work.  Can you give me something that would work for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @Eric; if you want to use substitute, `plot(1,1, main=substitute(Pr( Y == y ~'|'~ theta == xx, n==yy), list(xx=mytheta, yy=n)))`

Comment: Thanks!  Got it now!